# How to remove a certain file from php $_FILES array?

Tags: php

Sometimes when you wanna upload a number of files and a conf file within it, after you retrieve information from the conf file, it's no longer useful, how can you remove it from $_FILES array (not uploads folder)?

$FILES would be an associative array of index arrays, html like this:

```
<input type="file" name="my_file[]" multiple>
```

Comment: Altering superglobals is bad practice. Just make your code skip over the ones that you don't want to take an action on.

Answer (score 0):

To remove, 
    unset($_FILES['NameOfFile']);

Comment: it's an index array when you use <input name="my_file[]"> element

Answer (score 0):

Two answers to this:

1. **DON'T**. It is bad practice to alter the values of superglobals.
2. If you really, really must, you can do it like this:

   ```
   $index = 2; // the index of the file

   foreach (array_keys($_FILES['my_file']) as $key) {
       unset($_FILES['my_file'][$key][$index]);
   }
   ```